# Similar pyspark logic returns different number of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why do the following two lines of code produce a different result?

```
email_response.filter(f"first_response_date > date'2020-11-2'")
```

The above returns 176671203 rows.

```
email_response.filter(F.col("first_response_date") > F.lit("2020-11-2")).count()
```

The above returns 52063066 rows.

The logic appears identical, why do the results differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line is comparing the column to a **string** `"2020-11-2"`, not a date. If you add a `.cast("date")` to the second line, I guess you will get the same answer.

```
email_response.filter(F.col("first_response_date") > F.lit("2020-11-2").cast("date")).count()
```